# error con webpack laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

quise usar webpack pero me sale erro y no se como arreglarlo

```
app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at app.js:1
```

este es  mi archivo app.js tiene codigo de un componente en vue js

```
    require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('persona-component', require('./components/PersonaComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('post-component', require('./components/PostComponent.vue').default);
Vue.component('infinite-loading', require('vue-infinite-loading').default);
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    created: function(){
        this.getKeeps();
    },
    data: {
        keeps: []
    },
    methods: {
        getKeeps: function(){
            var urlKepps = 'tasks';
            axios.get(urlKepps).then(response => {
                this.keeps = response.data
            });
        },
        deleteKeep: function(keep){
            var url = "tasks/"+keep.id;
            axios.delete(url).then(response =>{
                this.getKeeps()
                alert('eliminado')
                this.getKeeps()
            });
        },
        editarKeep: function(keep){
            alert('eliminar');

        }
    }
});
```

este  es mi webpack

```
    mix.scripts(['resources/js/app.js',
    'resources/js/jquery.js',
    'resources/js/bootstrap.js',
    'resources/js/toastr.js'],
    'public/js/app.js')
   .styles(['resources/css/bootstrap.css',
            'resources/css/toastr.css'],
    'public/js/app.css');
```

Comment: perdon ya lo puse

Comment: Pero estás queriendo cargar directamente ese archivo en una vista?  Tenés que compilarlo y cargar el archivo compilado

Comment: ya lo compile no marca error npm